# 'WaitForAllTabsToStopLoading' error while trying to playback Code UI Test in Chrome

Tags: visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests

While trying to playback Code UI script in Chrome, I get the following error: WaitForAllTabsToStopLoading

Answer (score 0):

This issue started happening recently to me as well with Selenium 2.35 from VS2012.  Upgrading to the most recent chromedriver (v2.2) fixed the issue.